# MEF doesn't work on devices with Windows 8.1 or above

Tags: c#, .net, windows, mef

I use Managed Extensibility Framework in my .NET 4 WinForms application. Everything works perfectly fine on my Windows 8, on a fresh installation of Windows XP SP3 on Hyper-V, on Windows 7 and generally everywhere below Win 8.1.

The problem occurs only in Windows 8.1 or above - there are no errors or exceptions but no plugins are found.
I'm not attaching any code since I've tried running the official sample application for MEF from MSDN and even that doesn't work on 8.1 (https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/Simple-Calculator-MEF-1152654e). The exports defined in the main project work fine, but it can't find the one from DLL project.

I've tried both applications on few machines already and the result is always the same - everything works perfectly fine as long as it's below Windows 8.1...

Is there any bug in Windows 8.1 that prevents loading MEF extensions from DLLs...?

Comment: I would try it on an other computer. Our imports (dll based) work on both Win 8.1 and Win 10.

Comment: I've tried it on 3 computers already. 2 with Win 8.1 and 1 with Win 10, none of them could run the MSDN sample correctly...

Comment: I downloaded the sample and tried it. It *is* working. Probably you are making some mistake over and over again that does not do your intellect justice :-) Clear your mind, spell out the instructions and try again.

Comment: I'm not doing anything except for changing the catalog and building the solution. Have you tried the modulo operation? Adding and subtracting works fine for me too.

Comment: @Dabblernl Could you maybe think of a possible mistake I might be doing that makes it work perfectly fine on Win 8 and below while not working on 8.1 and above? That's the thing I can't seem to figure out here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Found the reason - the DLL containing the modulo operation is by default blocked by the system and the user needs to manually unblock it to make it work.

It would be nice if Windows at least noticed the user somehow that it blocked one of the files or even ask the user about it...

Anyway, after manually unblocking the DLLs, everything works fine:

[image: screenshot of "unblock" option in Windows 8.1+]

Comment: You are my savior!